# Did you remove the accepted answer percentage?

Tags: support

I can't find it anymore, below the user's flair.  Did you remove it ?  Why ?

I couldn't find [any subject about that in meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=accepted%20percentage) (which seems curious), so I hope I'm not duplicating something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember Arqade is a part of the larger Stack Exchange family of sites; if you don't find something on our meta, a good place to look is on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Accepted answers ratio is indeed no longer displayed on questions, and here's the relevant discussion:

- [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

In addition, every time you find yourself wondering whether something has changed, you should check out this handy topic:

- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

(where you can see "2013-01-22: Accept rates will no longer be shown. Like flag weight, they will continue to be calculated for backend use.")

Comment: Ow, so this is a larger decision.  Ok, thanks a lot for the clarification !